# SpeechRecognizer not transcribe voice from speakerphone on Samsung Galaxy S7 and above

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am developing an app to transcribe conversation during phone call, it works fine in Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6 (was able to transcribe voice on both mic and speakerphone). However, it not working (just able to transcribe voice from mic only) when testing on S7 (both using Android 7). Below is code that I used to start speech to text

```
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.getApplicationContext());
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en-US");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000);
    speechRecognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
```

Could it be a hardware issue or do I miss any configure option on my code? I did compare the hardware statistic on both S5 S6 and S7 but I could not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "voice.recognition.test")
```